# AS 3.0 || Starling || 2D infinite road creation

Tags: actionscript-3, starling-framework

I am trying to develop a infinite road with random obstacles coming through.
I am using starling framework. I don't know where to start. Any guide line will be appreciated.
Thank you
Cheers

Comment: 1: your road doesn't move, it's just an animation of one moving.  2: The obstacles are randomly generated at the horizon and animate to your rear.  3: Handle events as necessary during collisions.

Comment: same question asked in flashpunk forum in a last few days, you can check this answer, you can get the logic, çocuk oyuncağı: http://developers.useflashpunk.net/t/infinite-sidescroller-with-randomized-objects-flying-in/1049/4?u=alobarnon

and some important tricks
http://www.gamasutra.com/blogs/AdamSaltsman/20100929/6096/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A great first step would be using scrolling textures, probably. 
http://blog.krecha-games.com/scroll-image-extension-for-starling/

Or possibly if you need a curved road, something like this (AS3 but not starling)
http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-glowing-flowing-lava-river-using-bezier-curves-and-shaders--gamedev-919